# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined. Check the render method of DrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Getting below error while implementing NavigationDrawer with react-native.

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `DrawerNavigator`.

Comment: Please add code snippets to reproduce error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix this error: Check the render method of \`DrawerNavigator\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68636430/how-to-fix-this-error-check-the-render-method-of-drawernavigator)

Comment: @Rajendran Nadar, it is working but getting this error now: TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
    at DrawerItemList

Comment: Clear the metro cache, & re try.